# nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet - Spring Boot 2.2.8

Tags: json, spring-boot, hibernate

**Editado (26/10/20):** Me he encontrado con otro paradigma, pasar los valores de una entidad débil, entre Employee y Location (en español, Ubicación). La consola salta esta excepción:

**Spring Console**

```
2020-10-26 11:12:13.680 DEBUG 8564 --- [nio-9898-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    insert 
    into
        employee
        (departmentId, employeeChiefId, employeeLastNames, employeeNIF, employeeName, employeeRegisterDate, employeeShutDate, itemId, itemSetId, departmentLocationId, locationId) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        employee
        (departmentId, employeeChiefId, employeeLastNames, employeeNIF, employeeName, employeeRegisterDate, employeeShutDate, itemId, itemSetId, departmentLocationId, locationId) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2020-10-26 11:12:13.680 TRACE 8564 --- [nio-9898-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [INF]
2020-10-26 11:12:13.680 TRACE 8564 --- [nio-9898-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - [null]
2020-10-26 11:12:13.684 TRACE 8564 --- [nio-9898-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [Hernández]
2020-10-26 11:12:13.684 TRACE 8564 --- [nio-9898-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - [11223344S]
2020-10-26 11:12:13.684 TRACE 8564 --- [nio-9898-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [5] as [VARCHAR] - [xxxxxxxx]
2020-10-26 11:12:13.684 TRACE 8564 --- [nio-9898-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [6] as [VARCHAR] - [2020-10-22 15:00:00]
2020-10-26 11:12:13.684 TRACE 8564 --- [nio-9898-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [7] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
2020-10-26 11:12:13.684 TRACE 8564 --- [nio-9898-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [8] as [BIGINT] - [null]
2020-10-26 11:12:13.684 TRACE 8564 --- [nio-9898-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [9] as [BIGINT] - [null]
2020-10-26 11:12:13.684 TRACE 8564 --- [nio-9898-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [10] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
2020-10-26 11:12:13.684 TRACE 8564 --- [nio-9898-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [11] as [BIGINT] - [1]
2020-10-26 11:12:13.692  WARN 8564 --- [nio-9898-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000
2020-10-26 11:12:13.692 ERROR 8564 --- [nio-9898-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column 'departmentLocationId' cannot be null
2020-10-26 11:12:13.748  WARN 8564 --- [nio-9898-exec-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException:
```

**Location.java (Entidad débil)**

```
@Entity(name = "location")
@Table
public class Location implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "locationId")
    private Long locationId;

    @JoinColumn(name = "departmentLocationId", referencedColumnName = "departmentId", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    private Department department;

    @Column(name = "locationAbbreviation")
    private String locationAbbreviation;

    @Column(name = "locationDescription")
    private String locationDescription;

    public Location() {
    }
//Getters and setters

}
```

**Employee.java (Entidad fuerte que tiene que recibir las FKs de la débil)**

```
@Entity(name = "employee")
@Table
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "employeeId")
    private Long employeeId;

    @Column(name = "employeeName")
    private String employeeName;

    @Column(name = "employeeLastNames")
    private String employeeLastNames;

    @Column(name = "employeeNIF")
    private String employeeNIF;

    @JoinColumn(name = "departmentLocationId", referencedColumnName = "departmentLocationId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "locationId", referencedColumnName = "locationId")
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    private Location location;

    @JoinColumn(name = "departmentId", referencedColumnName = "departmentId")
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    private Department department;

    @JoinColumn(name = "employeeChiefId", referencedColumnName = "employeeId")
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.USE_DEFAULTS)
    private Employee employeeChief;

    @JoinColumn(name = "itemSetId", referencedColumnName = "itemSetId")
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.USE_DEFAULTS)
    private ItemSet itemSet;

    @JoinColumn(name = "itemId", referencedColumnName = "itemId")
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.USE_DEFAULTS)
    private Item item;

    @Column(name = "employeeRegisterDate")
    private String employeeRegisterDate;

    @Column(name = "employeeShutDate")
    private String employeeShutDate;

    public Employee() {
    }
```

Las tablas están estructuradas de la siguiente forma en MySQL:

[image: Tabla Location en MySQL]

[image: Tabla Employee en MySQL]

**JSON Entrada a nuevo Employee**

```
{
    "employeeName":"Josefa",
    "employeeLastNames":"Méndez",
    "employeeNIF":"11223344S",
    "location":{
            "departmentId":"INF",
            "locationId":"1"
        },
      "department":{
            "departmentId":"INF"
        },
    "employeeChief":{
            "employeeId":null
        },
    "itemSet":{
            "itemSetId":null
        },
    "item":{
            "itemId":null
        },
        "employeeRegisterDate":"2020-10-22 15:00:00",
    "employeeShutDate": null
}
```

Cómo se soluciona el paso de las FKs relacionadas con una entidad débil, por favor? Agradezco la ayuda y el aporte :)

---

Realizando unas pruebas para insertar un departamento (Department) junto con una Sede (Headquarters) en JSON, me ha saltado esta excepción.

**Entrada JSON**

```
{
     "departmentId":"ADMON",
     "departmentName":"Laboral",
     "headquarters": {
            "headquartersId":"CENTR"
     }
}
```

**Salida JSON**

```
{
  "timestamp": "2020-10-22T11:22:26.349+0000",
  "message": "could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet",
  "details": "uri=/api_xxxxx/v1/department"
}
```

Las entidades que he implementado son las siguientes:

**Headquarters.java**

```
@Entity(name = "headquarters")
@Table
public class Headquarters implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "headquartersId")
    private String headquartersId;

    @Column(name = "headquartersName")
    private String headquartersName;

    @Column(name = "headquartersAddress")
    private String headquartersAddress;

    @Column(name = "headquartersLocation")
    private String headquartersLocation;

    @Column(name = "headquartersWebSite")
    private String headquartersWebSite;

    public Headquarters() {
    }

//Getters and setters

}
```

**Department.java**

```
@Entity(name = "departament")
@Table
public class Department implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "departmentId")
    private String departmentId;

    @Column(name = "departmentName")
    private String departmentName;

    @JoinColumn(name = "headquartersId", referencedColumnName = "headquartersId", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    private Headquarters headquarters;

    public Department() {
    }

//Getters and setters

}
```

Las tablas en MySQL se muestran de esta manera:

[image: Tabla Department MySQL]

[image: Tabla Headquarters MySQL]

Los Service de cada una de las clases quedan tal que así:

**HeadquartersService.java**

```
@Service("headquartersService")
public class HeadquartersService implements IHeadquartersService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("headquartersRepository")
    private HeadquartersRepository headquartersRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Headquarters> findAllHeadquarterss() {
        return (List<Headquarters>) headquartersRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Headquarters> findHeadquartersById(String headquartersId){
        return headquartersRepository.findById(headquartersId);
    }

    @Override
    public Headquarters addHeadquarters(Headquarters headquarters){
        return headquartersRepository.save(headquarters);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteHeadquarters (Headquarters headquarters){
        headquartersRepository.delete(headquarters);
    }

    @Override
    public Headquarters updateHeadquarters(Headquarters headquartersDetails, Headquarters headquarters){

        headquarters.setHeadquartersName(headquartersDetails.getHeadquartersName());
        headquarters.setHeadquartersAddress(headquartersDetails.getHeadquartersAddress());
        headquarters.setHeadquartersLocation(headquartersDetails.getHeadquartersLocation());
        headquarters.setHeadquartersWebSite(headquartersDetails.getHeadquartersWebSite());

        return headquartersRepository.save(headquarters);
    }

}
```

**DepartmentService.java**

```
@Service("departmentService")
public class DepartmentService implements IDepartmentService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("departmentRepository")
    private DepartmentRepository departmentRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Department> findAllDepartments() {
        return (List<Department>) departmentRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Department> findDepartmentById(String departmentId){
        return departmentRepository.findById(departmentId);
    }

    @Override
    public Department addDepartment(Department department){
        return departmentRepository.save(department);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteDepartment (Department department){
        departmentRepository.delete(department);
    }

    @Override
    public Department updateDepartment(Department departmentDetails, Department department){

        department.setDepartmentName(departmentDetails.getDepartmentName());
        department.setHeadquarters(departmentDetails.getHeadquarters());

        return departmentRepository.save(department);
    }
}
```

Y los Controller de cada una se muestran de esta otra forma:

**HeadquartersController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api_aixina/v1")
public class HeadquartersController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("headquartersService")
    private HeadquartersService headquartersService;

    @GetMapping("/headquarters")
    public List<Headquarters> getAllHeadquarterss() {
        return headquartersService.findAllHeadquarterss();
    }

    @GetMapping("/headquarters/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Headquarters> getHeadquartersById(
            @PathVariable(value = "id") String headquartersId) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        Headquarters headquarters = headquartersService.findHeadquartersById(headquartersId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Headquarters not found on :: "+ headquartersId));
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(headquarters);
    }

    @PostMapping("/headquarters")
    public Headquarters createHeadquarters(@Valid @RequestBody Headquarters headquarters) { return headquartersService.addHeadquarters(headquarters); }

    @PutMapping("/headquarters/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Headquarters> updateHeadquarters(
            @PathVariable(value = "id") String headquartersId,
            @Valid @RequestBody Headquarters headquartersDetails) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        Headquarters headquarters = headquartersService.findHeadquartersById(headquartersId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Headquarters not found on :: "+ headquartersId));

        final Headquarters updatedHeadquarters = headquartersService.updateHeadquarters(headquartersDetails, headquarters);
        if  (updatedHeadquarters == null){
            return new ResponseEntity<Headquarters>(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED);
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(updatedHeadquarters);
        }
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/headquarters/{id}")
    public Map<String, Boolean> deleteHeadquarters(
            @PathVariable(value = "id") String headquartersId) throws Exception {
        Headquarters Headquarters = headquartersService.findHeadquartersById(headquartersId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Headquarters not found on :: "+ headquartersId));

        headquartersService.deleteHeadquarters(Headquarters);
        Map<String, Boolean> response = new HashMap<>();
        response.put("deleted", Boolean.TRUE);
        return response;
    }

}
```

**DepartmentController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api_aixina/v1")
public class DepartmentController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("departmentService")
    private DepartmentService departmentService;

    @GetMapping("/departments")
    public List<Department> getAllDepartments() {
        return departmentService.findAllDepartments();
    }

    @GetMapping("/departments/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Department> getDepartmentById(
            @PathVariable(value = "id") String departmentId) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        Department department = departmentService.findDepartmentById(departmentId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Department not found on :: "+ departmentId));
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(department);
    }

    @PostMapping("/department")
    public Department createDepartment(@Valid @RequestBody Department department) { return departmentService.addDepartment(department); }

    @PutMapping("/departments/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Department> updateDepartment(
            @PathVariable(value = "id") String departmentId,
            @Valid @RequestBody Department departmentDetails) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        Department department = departmentService.findDepartmentById(departmentId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Department not found on :: "+ departmentId));

        final Department updatedDepartment = departmentService.updateDepartment(departmentDetails, department);
        if  (updatedDepartment == null){
            return new ResponseEntity<Department>(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED);
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(updatedDepartment);
        }
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/department/{id}")
    public Map<String, Boolean> deleteDepartment(
            @PathVariable(value = "id") String departmentId) throws Exception {
        Department department = departmentService.findDepartmentById(departmentId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Department not found on :: "+ departmentId));

        departmentService.deleteDepartment(department);
        Map<String, Boolean> response = new HashMap<>();
        response.put("deleted", Boolean.TRUE);
        return response;
    }

}
```

Sin tener que usar DTO, cómo puedo pasar un objeto JSON Headquarters con su respectivo Id y que muestre el resultado de la inserción del dato?

Preguntas similares: [Exception (org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException) org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59774/exception-org-hibernate-exception-sqlgrammarexception-org-hibernate-exception)

["could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/342046/could-not-extract-resultset-sql-n-a-nested-exception-is-org-hibernate-excep)

Muchas gracias por anticipado :)

Comment: Por lo que he podido sacar de la traza de error, te dice que la columna 'departmentLocationId' no puede ser nula.

Lo que pienso es que, o estás tomando mal el valor en el controlador y seteando un null o que la petición al backend no se realiza de forma correcta y le llega null en vez de las propiedades.

Revisa qué datos recibes del front-end para saber si recibe null del front-end o estás llamando mal a la propiedad en el front-end o en el back-end y por eso recibes null al llamar a la propiedad.

Comment: @SergioGarridoDomínguez Vale entiendo esta parte que comentas. Aún así, cómo puedo asociar tanto departmentLocationId y locationId al propio entity Location? Hay más opciones aparte de JoinColumn para este escenario?

Comment: El locationId en tu base de datos es el ID de la entidad y debería ser autoincrementable y olvidarte de ello, que ya lo manejara la base de datos.

En cuanto al departmentLocationId, en la base de datos lo recibe como un número (ID), pero en Java debes setear la propiedad en sí. Por lo que, debes buscar el Department que tiene esa ID que recibes del JSON, y con eso setearlo a la Location.

Comment: @SergioGarridoDomínguez Entonces, en la parte MySQL, la tabla Location tiene solo la PK locationId? departmentLocationId quedaría como FK normal.

Comment: Depende de la relación entre ambas, ¿cuál es? ¿1 a muchos? ¿Muchos a muchos?

Comment: @SergioGarridoDomínguez Siempre las entidades débiles son de 1 a muchos.

Comment: Entonces es como te he dicho antes.

Comment: @SergioGarridoDomínguez Te compro la respuesta, muchas gracias. :)

Comment: Me alegro de haber sido de ayuda!

Comment: @SergioGarridoDomínguez Te mereces la recompensa a la pregunta. A ti! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final he prescindido de la FK asociada a departmentLocationId, y está eliminada tanto en la base de datos como del entity Employee, quedando de esta manera:

```
@Entity(name = "employee")
@Table
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "employeeId")
    private Long employeeId;

    @Column(name = "employeeName")
    private String employeeName;

    @Column(name = "employeeLastNames")
    private String employeeLastNames;

    @Column(name = "employeeNIF")
    private String employeeNIF;

    @JoinColumn(name = "locationId", referencedColumnName = "locationId")
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    private Location location;

    @JoinColumn(name = "departmentId", referencedColumnName = "departmentId")
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    private Department department;

    @JoinColumn(name = "employeeChiefId", referencedColumnName = "employeeId")
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.USE_DEFAULTS)
    private Employee employeeChief;

    @JoinColumn(name = "itemSetId", referencedColumnName = "itemSetId")
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.USE_DEFAULTS)
    private ItemSet itemSet;

    @JoinColumn(name = "itemId", referencedColumnName = "itemId")
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.USE_DEFAULTS)
    private Item item;

    @Column(name = "employeeRegisterDate")
    private String employeeRegisterDate;

    @Column(name = "employeeShutDate")
    private String employeeShutDate;

    public Employee() {
    }
```